# How to sort many2one choices other than by id in Sonata Admin?

Tags: symfony, sonata-admin

Everything is in the title: i can't manage to retrieve data otherwise than sorted by id. I would like them sorted by name, by example. How can I do that ?

```
$formMapper
        ->with('Général')
        ->add('name', 'text', array('label' => 'Nom'))
        ->add('allergen', 'entity', array(
            'label' => 'Allergène', 
            'class' => 'Proxymart\ProductBundle\Entity\Allergen', 
            'required' => false))
        ->end()
    ;
```

The result is this (sorted by id, not good):

[image: result]

Any help would be appreciated...

Answer (score 1):

One way would be to pass `query_builder` option, like this:

```
'query_builder' => function(\Doctrine\ORM\EntityRepository $repo) {
     return $repo->createQueryBuilder('a')
         ->orderBy('a.name', 'ASC');
 },
```